# Can't start Docker Daemon and can't clean docker containers

Tags: docker

My docker daemon can't start. When running

```
dockerd
```

With the debug flag, it seems it gets stuck loading unused containers since this are the last lines before it hangs:

```
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.352998608-05:00] Loaded container fe8646a0750d267143d06a3138e2afa482b5744398191156705219eeda2dfd70, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.360131801-05:00] Loaded container fee217b2865b6041f966d2c345e4ed948b8c1e250e491516be81cbb2a91832a7, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.368410531-05:00] Loaded container feae3a8597d12f0d3aaf7a70cffa8b7eafbcc0be4b0f9e4f755ea55031d7d9ac, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.369724660-05:00] Loaded container fed2cd064850fb9e6d2f38653ce020afc8d9257c290a08b5be56d60fad89b277, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.370485780-05:00] Loaded container febafbee8bcaefca179676020e10f266eab49227eee5f4c30b8642d04d077aa7, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.372800715-05:00] Loaded container fec9a082b345ffc810c99a1108ab1aa5d8245f2f4a6571d076c8b824216597e5, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.373839942-05:00] Loaded container fedb695539c51e3e0446bb30bc6a9e4d44fd5e9b8a01d63ed5de79134886500b, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.385171432-05:00] Loaded container fe8145beb93b01da59970bd95821263ed2864a17c17ae3be0843bb9aca272108, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.396431763-05:00] Loaded container feacc8b3f9c58a40f076af43ab3a1b628f44938fd9b43c05efe3ff42042eba14, isRunning: false
DEBU[2020-01-15T11:23:45.414911377-05:00] Loaded container fea608d6ca184588ec14036db9f63da7fd9d04e91d423e26348ca036ce9d643d, isRunning: false
```

The SO (ubuntu) hangs, probably due to memory error.
I checked the containers folder and there are more than 30k containers, and I don't have any need to save containers, only images. My idea was to clean the docker containers using

```
docker container prune
```

But since the docker daemon can't start, that command cannot be ran.
Any insights on what I can do to find the problem or how to delete unused containers?

Maybe if I could find a safe way to backup my images without docker daemon, then I could restart everything.

Comment: This commnad `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/containers/*` will remove **ALL** your containers... it is usefull for you?

Comment: @Schwarz54 if that is a safe way to remove containers then yes. I will try it.

Comment: when I told you **ALL** is **ALL** used and unused, take care about that